# Last-modified date not showing up in indexed documents

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

We have tried everything, pushing feeds, setting up fields in "document dates" screen to enable all documents in the index to contain a value for Last-modified date. Nothing seems to make documents retain a "last-modified date" in the index.

How does one enable a last-modified date for all documents in the index?

Note: the meta value will come from an external xml source (not a database).

Followed the [google instructions](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/64/metadata.html#ext_metadata_feed) for our gsa version (6.4.0.G.22).

Yes I know the GSA version is quite old, we've been told by our google-representative support team themselves, that updating the GSA to the latest version "should" resolve the problem, and by "should" I mean, their GSA did the same thing (no last-modified date) and updating our GSA is another can of worms story :)

Comment: Contact Google Support.  We probably can't help you as well as they can.

Comment: Will do eventually, wanna see first if anyone has ran into this problem before.

Comment: I suspect not.  My general gut feeling from Serverfault is that the majority of folk here would've used their own hand-rolled intranet search.. There's sod all in the way of questions about GSAs

Comment: Very unfortunate, AFAIK procedure is to talk to Google's support partners that provide support for the GSA's and in our case, we are the technical support for the client, so talking to Google's partner costs money. I am hopeful :)

Comment: Well, I'll upvote it.. But I doubt you'll get any fish biting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official answer this seems to be a bug and your best bet is to talk with Google directly.

However while the last modified date doesn't show up in the crawl diagnostics of an individual page, the date can be returned through the XML feed using the `&getfields=*` attribute.

You should see `<FS NAME="date" VALUE="xxx-xx-xx" />` element under each `<R>` element.